# Send echo command to an external xTerm

Tags: bash, logging, echo, xterm

I have a bash script, and I want to be able to keep a log in an xterm, and be able to send echo to it anytime.

How would I do this?

Comment: Please show some research effort and tell us what you have tried to solve this issue by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `GPG_TTY` variable in your `xterm` session. It should have the value similar to

```
GPG_TTY=/dev/pts/2
```

This method should be available for terminals that support [GNU Pinentry](https://gnupg.org/software/pinentry/index.html).

Another option to determine the current terminal name is to use

```
readlink /proc/self/fd/0
```

The last method applies only to Linux

Now if your bash script implements a command

```
echo "Hello, world!" > /dev/pts/2
```

This line should appear on the `xterm` screen.

Comment: There isn't a variable `GPG_TTY` in the xTerm session, but I did get the `echo -e "\e[91;1mTest" > /dev/pts/1` thing working. How would I find the right /dev/pts number though?

Comment: @JacobCollins I have updated the post. You could issue `readlink /proc/self/fd/0` from xterm command prompt

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work, but I found an easier way  :) thanks so much anyway

Comment: @JacobCollins You can share your solution as a separate post when the "answer your own question" link appears

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make a console by running an xterm with a while loop clearing the screen, reading the contents of the log file, pauseing for a second, then looping again. Here was the command:

```
xterm -T Console -e "while true: do cls && cat ${0}-LOG.txt && sleep 1; done"
```

Then to send something to the console:

```
echo -e "\e[91;1mTest" >> ${0}-LOG.txt
```

And the console will update each second.